# main class is not acceptable - при попытке создать exe в Intellij

Tags: java, javafx

Есть простенькая программа, для нее требуется создать exe. Работаю в Intellij
Делаю по стандартной схеме File>Project Structure>Artifacts>JavaFx Application.
Но при попытке указать Application class - указываю путь к маину и выдает ошибку Main is not acceptable. Спецификаторы доступа стоят public.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Answer (score 1):

**JavaFX** требует, что бы основной класс был наследником `javafx.application.Application` и должен переопределять метод `public void start(Stage primaryStage)`

Answer (score 0):

[Попробуйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884283/3212712) назначить директорию где лежит класс как `source root`

Для этого выделите папку, нажмите `ПКМ` и выберите `"Mark Directory as -> Source Root"`